# How to remove built-in datastore indexes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The app engine defines a built-in index for every field by default. I didn't create them, and I don't want them.

My actual entities are only consuming 159MB, but the indexes consume an additional 680MB. I am only ever going to be doing key-queries on these entities, so I do not need any indexes at all. How can I remove these?

**EDIT**: Output of `vacuum_indexes`:

```
Found 0 unused indexes on the server.

Details:
No indexes were deleted.

vacuum_indexes completed successfully.
```

Comment: Is this the Development server or the production server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not remove built-in indexes. They are built-in :)

What you can do is reduce the number of indexed used by your app's models. By default every property is indexed in AppEngine. I think you really mean about this.

To make a property unindexed, add a param to de property declaration like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    FirstName = db.StringProperty(Indexed=False)
    LastName = db.StringProperty(Indexed=False)
    ...
```

Thst's way, appengine will stop to use/create an index for that specific property. Next time you run you SDK console, indexes.yaml file will be updated automatically.

The last thing you need to do is execute `appcfg.py vacuum_indexes myapp/`. Read more about the last command on the [Appengine SDK docummentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Deleting_Unused_Indexes).

Comment: The idea bihind indexes is not about paying more or less. It's about performance. Here's the official Doc for Java https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Introduction_to_Indexes

Comment: Ok, so I already have 800k entities in the datastore. This doesn't tell me how to remove the indexes that are already there, it shows me how to not index fields in newly inserted entities.

Comment: `./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes myapp/war` https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Deleting_Unused_Indexes a Google search provide me that link. But before you remove an Index, you have to stop using it, making properties unindexed

Comment: Try the following: 1) Update your models declaration [unindexed property]. 2) Delete `datastore-indexes.xml` file. 3) Run a execute most app requests (This records indexes used by SELECTs. 4) See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Updating_Indexes and then https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Deleting_Unused_Indexes

Comment: Indexed=False should be in lower case. Otherwise, TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Indexed'
-->
indexed=False

Comment: @TravisWebb, I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

With the low-level Java API you need to use the setUnindexedProperty method for all properties you don't want to have an built-in index on.
There's no way of simply changing some definiton file and vacuuming to get rid of index entries that are already there.
The only way to remove those built-in index entries (or to create new ones) is to re-write all your entities. Be aware though, that deletion of one index entry on one single entity will count as 2 full writes against your quota as these are actually 2 index entries - one in ascending the other in descending order.